# Prolog, "or" operator for rule statments

Tags: prolog, operators

I am new to prolog and want to make a rule statement for whether 2 people are cousins.

This is my current code, I added "or" to where I need the `or` operator:

`cousins(E, F) :- siblings(A, C) or siblings(A, D) or siblings(B, C) or siblings (B, D), parent(A, E), parent(B, E), parent(C, F), parent(D, F).`

I need just one of the `siblings()` to pass, but all `parent()` must pass.

Comment: What site / textbook are you using? You should try http://www.amzi.com/AdventureInProlog/index.php or maybe http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pageid=online or maybe "The Art of Prolog" which actually starts with a family tree example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Prolog, an "or" operator is `;`. Or it can be achieved by having different clauses for the predicate.

Let's see what happens if your *first* alternative turns out to hold:

```erlang
cousins(          E, F):- 
  siblings(A, C), 
  parent(  A,     E), 
  parent(  B,     E), 
  parent(     C,     F), 
  parent(     D,     F).
```

***Or***, what happens if the 2nd holds?

```erlang
cousins(          E, F) :- 
  siblings(A, D), 
  parent(  A,     E), 
  parent(  B,     E), 
  parent(     C,     F), 
  parent(     D,     F).
```

Similar for 3rd and 4th:

```erlang
cousins(E, F) :- siblings(B, C), 
  parent(A, E), parent(B, E), parent(C, F), parent(D, F).

cousins(E, F) :- siblings (B, D), 
  parent(A, E), parent(B, E), parent(C, F), parent(D, F).
```

Now you have your "or" condition expressed by the four clauses.

But you must have left many important details out. You probably wanted to have two pairs of parents, so you need to add the inequalities: `parent(A, E), parent(B, E), A \= B` etc. But then, the new 2nd clause is just a copy of the 1st, up to some variables renaming; same for the 3rd and 4th clauses. It'll suffice to leave just one of each pair.

But why would you need to know the both parents of a person? You don't, really. What does it matter, if it's a mother or a father? It doesn't. So, in the end, just one clause will be sufficient:

```erlang
cousins(            E, F):- 
    siblings(A, C), 
    parent  (A,     E), 
    parent(     C,     F).
```

You still have to check for some *degenerate* cases, so you won't ever end up proclaiming a person their own cousin.